# How to paint a sector in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have to paint a sector of circle in flutter. I used this code

```
canvas.drawArc(
    Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height - 50),
        radius: size.width / 2),
    degrees,
    width,
    true,
    paint);
```

and it worked fine. However for some inevitable reasons I can't use this method and I have to use the method

```
canvas.drawPath()
```

For that I need a path but it only has options to create arc and not sector.

Comment: did you check `Path` documentation? doesn't it have any methods related to "arc"?

Comment: it has but it gives arc and not sector.

Comment: so call `Path#moveTo()` and `Path.close()`

Comment: move to where? I called moveTo with the coordinates of the center and still the same.

Comment: wait thanks....instead of moveTo I used line to center and it worked...thanks

Comment: `"instead of moveTo"`? no - you have to use `moveTo` - i just check that and it seems you dont need `close` method but you have to use starting `moveTo`

Comment: okay I'll try that but for now it works. Also any specific reason why I should start using moveTo ?

Comment: `Path path = Path()..arcTo(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height -
        50),radius: size.width / 2), degrees, width, true,)..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height -
        50)..close();` This Worked

Comment: ok, but less intuitive imho...

Comment: okay now I understand what you're saying. Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path#arcTo` documentation says:

> If the `forceMoveTo` argument is false, adds a straight line
>   segment and an arc segment.
>   [...]
>   The line segment added if `forceMoveTo` is false starts at the
>   current point and ends at the start of the arc.

so this code will draw a segment:

```
Offset center = Offset(250, 250);
Rect rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: 200);
Path path = Path()
  // set the "current point"
  ..moveTo(center.dx, center.dy)
  ..arcTo(rect, pi / 4, pi / 2, false);
canvas.drawPath(path, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to create a path with the same parameters you used in drawArc()

try something like

```
Path.arcTo(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height - 
50),radius: size.width / 2), degrees, width, true,)
```

then use the returned path in canvas.drawPath()

Comment: it gives an arc and not a sector.